# .gitignore overly ignores files

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm working on a project on linux, with git version 1.8.x .
I tried to set some rules with .gitignore and quickly realized that listing everything you don't want to track is not what I actually want.
So I tried instead to precise which patterns git should track, ie:

```
*

#code files
!**/*.cpp
!**/*.h
```

But then, git doesn't track any new files anymore.
So is it possible to find a way to make it works?
Moreover using !**.cpp works only for the currents folders files.

Thanks o/

Comment: @zerkms the gitignore file is often used to "ignore everything... except these"

Comment: @Samuel O'Malley: keen to share a link to any more or less popular/famous project that does that?

Comment: @zerkms the fact that nobody (or big project) does it don't prevent you to do it. My common sense told me here that using 4 lines that surround everything is better than 999 lines which could still have some fails... Moreover there is no other files used to manage what you wanna track or not, so gitIGNORE can actually be used to KEEP some files too..

Comment: @Max: "don't prevent you to do it" --- I didn't say so. I was just told that "gitignore file **is often** used to". And I'm quite surprised that it's not possible to provide examples. Perhaps I'm missing the word "often" meaning. What I'm not surprised, is that among the projects that follow it - there is no widely known. For some magical reasons known projects can avoid following such a strange technique.

Comment: @zerkms. I use this *strange* technique on a daily base as it's very neat and surely less complicated than ignoring every single extension. Whitelisting is generally preferable to blacklisting. Finally there are also several questions on the subject on SO.

Comment: @Gabriele Petronella: that's interesting. In neither C++, .NET, or php projects I suffer any issues with just ignoring not necessary items. And it always was pretty compact :-S

Comment: @zerkms have you ever tried ignoring the temp files generated by a LaTeX compiler? If you just care about the `.tex` files it's about 50 lines vs 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#Ignore everything
*

#Whitelist subdirectories
!*/

#Whitelist the gitignore itself
!.gitignore

#Whitelist .cpp and .h files
!*.h
!*.cpp
```

---

#### Remarks

- remember to include the .gitignore itself
- `*` ignores everything, directories included. Explicitly whitelisting subdirectories still ignores the files they contain, but it allows you to whitelist recursively
- with the previous point in mind, you can now just use `!*.fileext` as a pattern to whilelist single extensions

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add `!.gitignore` so it doesn't ignore itself!

```
#ignore everything
*
#Whitelist subdirectories - thanks to @Gabriele Petronella
!*/    

#except these:
!*.cpp
!*.h
!.gitignore
```