# Git recursive unignore file types

Tags: git, gitignore

I have the following project structure:

```
A
├── a.py
├── B
│   └── b.py
└── C
```

where I would like to ignore all contents of `A`, but include all `*.py` files recursively.
My `.gitignore` looks like this:

```
A/*
!A/**/*.py
```

which does not seem to give the desired behavior - only `a.py` is tracked in this case. What am I missing? I would like to avoid defining subdirectory-specific rules like `!A/B/*.py`.

Comment: There is a nicer way to not ignore directories: `!*/` See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11853075/7976758 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/19672434/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgitignore%5D+recursive+include+directories

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `A/*` is that it matches `A/B` and when a directory first is excluded, children of it are unavailable ("It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded").

So when excluding everything under `A` there is no way out of including all the directories again. You can however split the directories and pyhton files re-inclusion like the following:

```
A/*

!A/B
A/B/*
!A/C
A/C/*

!**/*.py
```

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping there was a nicer way to do this